Can you handle all client interactions within a server action in Nextjs? How do get cookie-authentication working
Context
I am using django-rest-framework with simple-jwt authentication configured with a NextJS/React frontend, and when making a request to my django server from a react server component, I realised that there is a gap in my knowledge.
Until that point, I was only making requests to my server from client components (users clicking on buttons to perform crud operations), and therefore my cookie package, js-cookie, was working just fine. But when trying to GET all the user's groups on a dashboard page from a server component, the server was returning undefined tokens, leading to anonymous users in my backend.
My solution
I now essentially have two "api_request" files where one uses js-cookie if I'm on the client and one that uses cookies from next/headers and I use them if I'm on a client or server component, respectively. Keeping those environments in sync is, however, a pain and also messy code for repeating myself in two files.
My questions
Is there a way around this?
Could I essentially let ANY client interaction be handled in a server action so I'm only in one environment?
